# Choose right method in Controller according to the forms - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I have two models: **Entreprise & Prospect**

```
 create_table "entreprises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "adresse"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "siret"
    t.string   "numtva"
    t.string   "tel"
    t.integer  "prospect_id"
  end

  create_table "prospects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "entreprise_id"
  end
```

Prospects **belongs_to** entreprises, and Entreprise **has_many** Prospects.

-

My issue :

I have two buttons : **Create a new entreprise** or **reate a new prospect**.

I have two way to create a new prospect :

- Under my entreprise because an entreprise has_many prospects
- Directly from navbar with "create prospect" button

So I have two forms :

If we click on "create prospect" (create method in my controller):

```
<%= form_for :prospects, url: prospects_path do |f| %>


  <p>
    <%= f.label :entreprises %><br><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :entreprise_id, Entreprise.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>

  </p><br>
  <p>
     <%= f.label :full_name %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :full_name %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :email %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

If we create prospect under entreprise ("directcreate" method in my controller) :

```
<%= form_for([@entreprise, @entreprise.prospects.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :full_name %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :full_name %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :email %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

My Controller for Prospects :

```
class ProspectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @prospects = Prospect.all.limit(15).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @prospect = Prospect.new
  end

  def directcreate
    @prospect = Prospect.new(entreprise_params)

    if @prospect.save
      redirect_to @prospect
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def create
    @entreprise = Entreprise.find(params[:entreprise_id])
    @prospect = @entreprise.prospects.create(params[:prospect].permit(:full_name, :email))

    redirect_to entreprise_path(@entreprise)
  end

  def destroy
    @entreprise = Entreprise.find(params[:entreprise_id])
    @prospect = @entreprise.prospects.find(params[:id])
    @prospect.destroy

    redirect_to entreprise_path(@entreprise)
  end

end
```

**My problème is that the "create" method in my controller is the only one who works.. and not "directcreate" method.**

--
**QUESTION : How can I do to choose the controller I want according to the form ?**

My question is probably not well ask.

FYI I try this in my new.html.erb :

```
  <%= render 'formdirect', :controller => "directcreate" %>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you use `accept_nested_attribute` in your model?

Comment: use `  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prospects` in your entreprise model and create prospects fields in form with `field_for`

Comment: I did it, but when I save my new prospect, I get an error "RecordNotFound in ProspectsController#create" and that show me "Create" method from my controller and not "directcreate" method.

Comment: "Directly from navbar with "create prospect" button" with this option you can create prospect based on entreprise  in different view

Comment: `@prospect = Prospect.new(entreprise_params)` this seems mistake

Comment: I already have to different views, with two differents forms. My issue is in my ProspectsController : I set two method "create" and "directcreate" for each view. But only the first one is working for the two forms/views..  I don't know how to link my submit button to the directcreate method.

Comment: show me your routes with `rake  routes`,and if possible share repo with me

Comment: Thanks Uzaif : https://github.com/FlorianCEO/CRM

Comment: let me look into it

Comment: where can we communicate i need to ask some question,does it good if we communicate over skype?

Comment: yep : Florian_designisvital

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You just have to explicitly choose your controller action.

```
<%= form_for([@entreprise, @entreprise.prospects.build], :url => { :action => : directcreate }) do |f| %>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :full_name %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :full_name %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
     <%= f.label :email %> <br>
     <%= f.text_field :email %><br>
  </p><br>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```